# I am trying access the REST webservice from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying access the REST  webservice(POST method) from javascript. In one of the solution suggested to add the CORS plugin in browser but i could not get the data.Can you please suggest any solution without the plugin which can be addes in javascript code.But getting the below error.

Error:
**test_rest_service.html:36 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.16.11.104:8080/Zurich_validate_user/rest/GetInfo/validateUser. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.doFunction @ test_rest_service.html:36onclick @ test_rest_service.html:9
test_rest_service.html:36 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load**

Comment: Do you have access over the REST api? Then, enable CORS in that api